# select distinct timestamp as DD/MM/YYYY mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple rows for `itemDate` (timestamp) like below:

```
itemDate
2013-04-09 17:24:31
2013-04-09 10:24:31
2013-04-08 12:20:30
```

When I use `SELECT DISTINCT(itemDate) FROM item;`, I am getting two rows for 2013-04-08.

I want to get the date of different date (based on `YYYY-MM-DD`) ignoring whether the time is different for the same day.

The result that I need should be like the following, when I query from that table:

```
itemDate
2013-04-09
2013-04-08
```

Comment: what is the column type of itemDate?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That's because those values are different. If you're trying to do this by date then use the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(itemDate)) FROM item;
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in spring JPA query methods?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative from the other answer is to use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(itemDate, '%Y-%m-%d') ItemDate 
FROM   Item
GROUP  BY DATE_FORMAT(itemDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfaf5e/3

Answer (score 1):

On my side, I have tried the different options suggested above but the Sybase DB I use is rejecting me:

```
Error: Function 'DATE' not found. If this is a SQLJ function or SQL function, use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce a large amount of output).
```

My colleague gave me this and works OK

```
SELECT distinct(CONVERT(varchar(20), timestamp, 111)) FROM HistoOrder
```

I use 111 but you can find code list here
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp